# Recursion in tree traversal

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, tree

I'm new to the concept of graphs and trees.Below is the inorder tree traversal of tree.

```
 if(n!=null){
     treeTraversal(n.left);
     System.out.println(n.val);
     treeTraversal(n.right);
 }
```

I'm not able to understand the flow as it involves recursion. Can somebody explain me how does control flow takes place with respect to stack.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say I have a tree which is something like:

```
    4
   / \
  2   5
 / \
1   3
```

Your code will first put the recurse through the left children 4 -> 2 -> 1. Since 1 does not have a left child (it is null), it will print 1 and then pop the stack. Next up in the recursion is 2. It will print 2 then traverse the right child of 2 i.e 3. It will print 3, then pop the stack. Then it will print 4, then 4's right child 5. The sequence of prints will be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. [Here](https://visualgo.net/bst) is a good animation too.

Answer (score 2):

The image shows the execution of the code with a simple tree, it should help you to understand how recursion works, just follow the arrows.

Under each stack there is the tree diagram that shows in yellow the current node (click the image to expand it):

[image: tree recursion]

Comment: Which software did you use for the graphs, are the graphs automatically generated ?

Answer (score 1):

This is an inOrder traversal you first visit left child if exist if not you print the nod and the you travers to left node[image]
for example in this tree your code out put will be
 10, 4, 11, 2, 5, 9, 1, 7, 6, 8, 3
We have `preOrder` and `postOrde` traversal as well

preOrder

```
preorder(Node N)
if (N != null)
Visit N;
for each child Y of N
preorder(Y);
```

and  post order

```
postorder(Node N)
if (N != null)
for each child Y of N
postorder(Y);
Visit N;
```